# How to change diagnostics storage location per service configuration in Azure SDK 2.5

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-diagnostics

In Azure SDK 2.5 the storage account is set in the wadcfgx of the role like this :

```
<PrivateConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
<StorageAccount name="myDiagnosticAccount" endpoint="https://core.windows.net/" />
```

The problem is that I want to have separate diagnostics accounts for staging and production. Like this:

For staging

```
<PrivateConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
<StorageAccount name="myProductionDiagStorageAccount" endpoint="https://core.windows.net/" />
</PrivateConfig>
```

and for production

```
<PrivateConfig xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2010/10/DiagnosticsConfiguration">
<StorageAccount name="myStageDiagStorageAccount" endpoint="https://core.windows.net/" />
</PrivateConfig>
```

But I do not see any possible way to do this since this config is per role and not per service configuration. In the previous SDK I used to set two different diagnostics connection string - “Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString” - and everything worked fine.

How can I achieve this now in SDK 2.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct. With SDK 2.5, it is not possible to define different storage accounts for different deployment environments.

One possibility would be to keep two separate diagnostics configuration files (one for staging & other for production). You would need to keep diagnostics disabled during deployment and once the code is deployed, you can enable the diagnostics using [`Set-AzureServiceDiagnosticsExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495270.aspx) Cmdlet.

In fact, it seems like recommended approach based on this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2014/12/02/windows-azure-diagnostics-upgrading-from-azure-sdk-2-4-to-azure-sdk-2-5.aspx (See the section titled `Enabling diagnostics extension through PowerShell`). From the blog post:

> Since Azure SDK 2.5 uses the extension model the diagnostics
>   extension, the configuration and the connection string to the
>   diagnostic storage are no longer part of the deployment package and
>   cscfg. All the diagnostics configuration is contained within the
>   wadcfgx. The advantage with this approach is that diagnostics agent
>   and settings are decoupled from the project and can be dynamically
>   enabled and updated even after your application is deployed.
>
> Due to this change some existing workflows need to be rethought –
>   instead of configuring the diagnostics as part of the application that
>   gets deployed to each environment you can first deploy the application
>   to the environment and then apply the diagnostics configuration for
>   it.  When you publish the application from Visual Studio this process
>   is done automatically for you. However if you were deploying your
>   application outside of VS using PowerShell then you have to install
>   the extension separately through PowerShell.

**UPDATE - 26-May-2015**

SDK 2.6 actually supports different storage accounts for different deployment environments. From the [release notes](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/azure-sdk-dotnet-release-notes-2_6/):

> The Diagnostics storage account can now be specified in the service
>   configuration (.cscfg) file **making it easier to use different
>   diagnostics storage accounts for different environments**.

If you are already using SDK 2.5, I would recommend upgrading it to SDK 2.6.

Comment: Ouch. This means I was right when I decided to migrate to v2.4 instead of v2.5

Comment: Ouch indeed! Unless someone has a need for ETW in their Cloud Services, my recommendation would be to stick to 2.4 and hope things would change for better in 2.6.

Comment: Is it possible to run a post-build event and edit the wadcfgx directly right before the publish?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know about this. You can give it a try and see if that works.